# A question about scaling

Tags: functions, functional-equations

One wants the function $\Delta ^2$ to be such that, $\Delta^2(k,\tau) = \Delta^2(\frac{k}{\lambda ^{\frac{4}{n+3}}}, \lambda \tau )$. Now from this how does this follow that, the following holds,

$\Delta^2(k,\tau) = \Delta^2(\frac{k}{k_{NL}})$ where $k_{NL}^{n+3}  \propto \tau ^{-4}$

?

Is there some uniqueness about it?

Comment: For the second equation, the function has differing numbers of arguments.

Comment: Also, should it be $\Delta^2$ everywhere, you initially wrote $\Delta$?

Comment: @Lucas The issue with the number of variables is the crux of the scenario - that if $\Delta^2$ has to satisfy the given scaling then necessarily it has to be a single variable function of that combination - thats the claim I want to understand.

Comment: o_O I'm quite confused. Perhaps you could add a little context, in most other situations where the form $f(x,y)$ denotes a function $X\times Y\rightarrow Z$, $f(x)$ denotes a completely different type of function $X\rightarrow Z$. Explaining things expressed in unconventional notation requires additional context from which to deduce the meaning of the notation.